# (Visual Studio 2019 C++ WinForms) "MissingManifestResourceException" exception when changing the icon in properties

Tags: c++, winforms, exception, icons, visual-studio-2019

So I just changed the icon property of the form to an ico file I made for it and generated. this line of code

```
this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
```

But now when I debug it, the program throws this exception at me (there are no errors in the error list):

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "CppCLRWinformsProjekt.Form1.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly

I added the ico file to resource files and it still threw this exception at me. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I modified the icon file and didn't get the error you said, make sure the icon file is available and place the icon file in the project folder.

Comment: The icon file is in the project folder, before adding it to the resources folder, I placed it in the project folder, then added it to the resources folder. This had no effect however.

Comment: I suggest you look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702543/visual-c-throwing-unhandled-exception-from-setting-forms-icon) and also check if the file path is in English, using other languages may cause errors.

Comment: The file path is in English. Also I tried this `this->Icon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(L"iconblack.ico");` from this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417832/c-windows-forms-application-icon-exception and it seemed to work and runs perfectly fine, but when I run it on my laptop, it loses its icon (but gets it back when in the recycle bin for some reason) and straight up refuses to run at all. It only works on my machine but no other. (must be to do with it searching for the icon and raising an exception because it can't find it on my machine)

Comment: Any reply yet??